# how to update (cookieconsent2, crawler, realurl) extension on typo3 version 8 to 9

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

**I upgraded typo3 version 8 to 9.**

There are some extension that can not update for version9

**extensions: cookieconsent2, crawler, realurl**

These extension do not exits for version-9 but installed in version-8, what is solution for that.

how i can use it or what is alternate for typo3 version-9

Thanks AbdulQayyum.

Answer (score 1):

**crawler** is about to get ready for v9 https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/projects/3. If you do not have a complicated setup, you can just have your frontend crawled by something else, e.g. `wget -r https://your-site.com` as a workaround in the meantime. You probably want EXT:indexed_search to work. This automatically updates the search index when cacheable pages are visited.

**realurl** is not needed in v9. SEO-routes are now part of the core. You need a site configuration (this is a write-up how it looks like: https://typo3worx.eu/2018/10/typo3-site-management-and-routing/) and that's all.

**cookieconsent2** you may ask the developers if it will get updated. If not, there are alternatives: https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=cookie+consent